# Merging two git repositories with different structure

Tags: git, merge

I have two git repos. One of them has been copied in the past from another. The copy was created by copying sources and then commiting in one commit. Additionaly sources has been moved to "sources" directory. Now I need to merge second repo back to the first one. In fact I need to merge /sources/* subdirectory of second one to /* of the first one preserving history.

How can achieve that in git?

Comment: Did you consider [subtree merges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)?

Comment: No i don't. As I understood git read-tree can read tree from remote into subdirectory in local repo. I have opposite situation.